# Dual displays not working properly, getting only low resolution

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, display

#### My hardware:

I just installed [Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (Precise Pangolin)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) and I have been unable to get my dual 1920x1080 monitors working properly with my [GeForce GTX 670 FTW](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-2678-KR).

#### The problem:

Whenever I get to the login screen both of my monitors display a purple back ground with small white dots and are mirroring each other (I can still see the mouse and move it).

In order to see the log in screen I have to unplug one of my monitors then plug it back in to the GPU, when I do this both monitors are now showing the login screen properly but are mirrored and **stuck at a 1024x768 resolution** and when I move my mouse to the right side of the screen the desktop slides over and disappears. When I move the mouse back over to the left of the screen the desktop slides back into place.

#### What I have tried:

I went into the display setting and tried to fix this but I am only given 1024x768 and 800x600 resolution options and when I unchecked mirror displays and click apply it defaults back to mirroring displays.

I believe this is a driver issue but I have no idea now to fix it ideas?

Comment: I think what you need is a proper xorg.conf file. I have dual monitor setup and what you described happens to me whenever I boot mine without xorg.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try (re)installing your Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did that and got this it seems like it didn't install anything?

james@james-Z68X-UD3H-B3:~$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia
[sudo] password for james: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia
james@james-Z68X-UD3H-B3:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-current is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Sorry I don't now how to do that terminal copy thing properly and this looks like a mess of text.

Comment: To paste in the terminal press `ctrl`+`shift`+`v`

Comment: Could you post you installed Nvidia packages here using `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia` so we can help you further?

Comment: Also with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` you forgot the `*` (the most essential part).

Comment: Ok this is what I got 


nvidia-common     install
nvidia-current     install
nvidia-current-updates    install
nvidia-experimental-310    install
nvidia-settings     install
nvidia-settings-experimental-310  install
nvidia-settings-updates    instal

Comment: and i will redo it with the *

Comment: I have redone the purge and install and this time I believe it preformed the proper actions. What next?

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No all of the same problems are still accruing.

Comment: Did you reboot your machine? New drivers get applied at startup.

Comment: Yes I preformed a reboot.

Comment: Hmm that's too bad. I'm sorry but I cannot help you any further, for this goes beyond my limited expertise.

Comment: That's fine thank-you for your time and suggestions